# jquery id selector echoed php? not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
    //play.php
echo' <div id="new_char" style="text-align:center; position:relative; top: 100px;"><center>
        You do not have a character! <br> Make one...<br><br>
        <form method="post" >
            Character Name: <input type="text" name="name" size="25"> <br>
            Class: <select name="class">
                ';
                $classinfo = "select * from classes";
                $classinfo2 = mysql_query($classinfo) or die("could not select classes");

                while($classinfo3 = mysql_fetch_array($classinfo2) )
                {
                echo"<option>$classinfo3[type]</option>";
                }
                echo' 
            </select><br />
            <div id="new_char_error"> </div>
            <br />
            <input id="make_char" type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
        <table border="0"  cellspacing="30">
            <tr><td  valign="top">
                </td>
                <td valign="top" >
                    <b style="text-align:center;">Class Starting Modifiers</b>
                    ';
                    $selectclass="select * from classes";
                    $selectclass2=mysql_query($selectclass) or die("couldnt get classes");
                    echo'

                    <table border="1" bordercolor="black" bgcolor="#fffffff">
                        <tr><td font color="cc0033"> Class </td> <td font color="cc0033"> Attack </td> <td font color="cc0033"> Defense </td>  <td font color="cc0033"> Endurance </td>  </tr> <br>

                        ';

                        while($selectclass3=mysql_fetch_array($selectclass2)) {
                        echo " <tr><td> $selectclass3[type]</td> <td> $selectclass3[attack]</td>  <td> $selectclass3[defense]</td>   <td> $selectclass3[maxendurance]</td> </tr>";
                        }
                        echo'
                    </table>
                </td></tr></table></center>
</div>
';
<script>
$("#make_char").click(function() {
$.ajax({
url:'character_scripts/new_char.php',
success: function(data) {
$('#new_char_error').html(data);
}
}); 
});
</script>
```

Is it possible to use a div that is echoed through php as a jquery selector? I have a form that is not being submitted when the submission is clicked. All the code on new_char.php looks good. Ive tested all the loops and possible variation of the codes structure during runtime, all I can think of is that jquery can not use a selector that is echoed in php. but Im not that familiar with jquery and did not find the answer when searching online.

ps:
The function is a separate file and that is not the entire files posted, (to conserve space)

Comment: please  format your question properly ... its hurting my eyes

Comment: Just found the answer  in the related column. thanks anyway.

Comment: You have syntax error in your JS code in the line `url='character_scripts/new_char.php',`. The equal sign `=` must be colon `:`.

Answer (score 0):

If you could post what you found, you might help others who've come here looking for an answer to the same problem.

Im guessing it was something simple like a missing semi or a typo as jquery really shouldnt care how your tag got the selector

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First check jQuery is loading properly or not.

After then following code will work not directly in php file

```
$("#make_char").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                    url='character_scripts/new_char.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#new_char_error').html(data);
                    }
            }); 
    });
```

you should write like below.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#make_char').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                    url='character_scripts/new_char.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#new_char_error').html(data);
                    }
            }); 
    });</script>";
```